# Getting the private ip of the machine in Puppet

Tags: linux, puppet

I am just thinking is there a way of getting the private Ip of the machine and using that in our puppet script, so let suppose we have the script to show the IP as:

```
class test{

    $my_ip=<some code>

    file{'print_ip_to_my_file':
       path => "/tmp/ip.txt",
       content => "This is test file and the private ip is : ${my_ip}"
    }
}
```

How can I get the **private Ip** in the file?

Comment: ifconfig not working? You will get local IP through it.

Comment: I am writing the puppet script, I want to get in puppet script, I want to make a manifest with run time ip getting of the machine on which the manifest is running

Comment: Does the facter ipaddress variable have what you need? Use:   $my_ip = $::ipaddress

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What do you mean by private ip of the machine ?

If you have facter installed, you can do,

```
 facter --puppet
```

to get a list of facts about the machines. Many of these facts will point to ipaddresses and other network parameters used by the machine.

```
 facter --puppet | grep ipaddress
 ipaddress => xxx.yy.zz.abc
 ipaddress_eth0 => xxx.yy.zz.abc
 ipaddress_lo => 127.0.0.1

 facter --puppet | grep network
```

In your code you can do,

```
 $my_ip = $::ipaddress
```

Comment: I am getting the exception in facter, how to install facter now is the question?

Comment: However you are installing puppet, same way you can install facter. It is a package name and it is available in the puppetlab repo.

Comment: for those who have problem with facter installation use:
gem install facter